# How come (let ((x 'huh?)) (cons (boundp 'x) x)) evaluates to (NIL . HUH?)?

Tags: common-lisp

I do not understand this:

```
CL-USER> (let ((x 'huh?)) (cons (boundp 'x) x))
(NIL . HUH?)
```

I had expected that inside the `let` expression above, `x` would be bound, and therefore that the whole expression would have evaluated to `(t . huh?)`.  Or else, if (contrary to my expectation) `x` was not bound in the `let`'s body, then at least that the evaluation of the expression above would have resulted in an error (on account of my having passed an unbound variable as the second argument to `cons`).

To add to my confusion, the Common Lisp HyperSpec's description for `boundp` [says](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_boundp.htm):

> Returns true if symbol is bound; otherwise, returns false.

...where the word "bound" is hyperlinked to this [glossary definition](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/26_glo_b.htm#bound) (my emphasis)<sup>1</sup>:

> bound adj., v.t. 1. adj. having an associated denotation in a binding.  **``The variables named by a let are bound within its body.''** See unbound. 2. adj. having a local binding which shadows[2] another. ``The variable *print-escape* is bound while in the princ function.'' 3. v.t. the past tense of bind.

Furthermore, the CLHS's documentation for [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm) says the following (my emphasis):

> ...all of the variables *varj* are **bound** to the corresponding values; ...

Granted, the HyperSpec's page for `boundp` (which I already linked to earlier) *also* has the following example:

```
(let ((x 2)) (boundp 'x)) =>  false
```

...which indeed would justify the assertion that what I observed is in fact "officially documented behavior", but this narrowly correct justification is little comfort in light of everything else I've cited above.

Could someone please resolve for me this whopping (and hopefully only apparent) contradiction?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I realize that the highlighted phrase above is just an example of how the word "bound" would be used in a sentence, but it would be a truly perverse example if what it stated was exactly the opposite of what is actually the case for Common Lisp.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a bit confusing, the spec for [`BOUNDP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_boundp.htm) does however say that:

> The function **bound** [sic (it should be **boundp**)] determines only whether a symbol has a value in the global environment; *any lexical bindings are ignored*.

So it only informs you if a given symbol is bound in the global environment, which happens if the variable has its value cell set to a value (see [`SYMBOL-VALUE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_5.htm)),
or the variable is declared **special** and was previously bound by a `let` form. This second case happens notably for variables declared with `defvar` and `defparameter`, but also any variable you declare as special:

```
(let ((%my-var% 0))
  (declare (special %my-var%))
  ...)
```

Note that to each time you want to use `%my-var%` you need to use that declaration, except if you declaimed it globally.

```
(defun use-my-var (input)
  (declare (special %my-var%))
  (print `(:my-var ,%my-var% :input ,input)))
```

When you write the `use-my-var` function, you have normally no problem identifying that `input` is bound, in fact a compiler would warn you if that was not the case. For lexical scopes, `(boundp x)` would compile down to a constant value, T or NIL. It is more interesting to check if the `symbol-value` of a symbol is globally bound or dynamically bound.

Here above, since `%my-var%` is a special variable, it can be bound or not in different calling contexts:

```
(let ((%my-var% 0))
  (declare (special %my-var%))
  (use-my-var 1))
=> (:my-var 0 :input 1)

(use-my-var 0)
;; ERROR: The variable %MY-VAR% is unbound.
```

Answer (score 5):

`boundp` is for determining whether symbols are bound in the *global* environment. Note the following two examples from the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_boundp.htm):

```lisp
(let ((x 2)) (boundp 'x)) ;=>  false  
(let ((x 2)) (declare (special x)) (boundp 'x)) ;=>  true
```

The notes at the bottom of the page say:

> The function `bound` determines only whether a symbol has a value in the global environment; any lexical bindings are ignored.

The appearance of `bound` in the note instead of `boundp` seems to be a typo. In any case, [CLTL2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node78.html#SECTION001111000000000000000) was a bit more specific about this:

> `boundp` is true if the dynamic (special) variable named by *symbol* has a value; otherwise, it returns `nil`.

Note that `fboundp` has a similar restriction; here is an example from the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fbound.htm):

```lisp
(flet ((my-function (x) x))  
  (fboundp 'my-function)) ;=>  false
```

There isn't much point in `boundp` handling lexical variables. From the HyperSpec [3.1.2.1.1.1 Lexical Variables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abaaa.htm):

> A lexical variable always has a value. There is no operator that introduces a binding for a lexical variable without giving it an initial value, nor is there any operator that can make a lexical variable be unbound.

This is to say that lexical variables are *always* bound in their lexical environments. But dynamic variables *may* be either [bound or unbound](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abaab.htm), and which of the two is the case can depend upon the environment in which the question is asked:

> The value part of the binding for a dynamic variable might be empty; in this case, the dynamic variable is said to have no value, or to be unbound. A dynamic variable can be made unbound by using `makunbound`....

> A dynamic variable is unbound unless and until explicitly assigned a value, except for those variables whose initial value is defined in this specification or by an implementation.